# Build.gradle unable to connect to maven repo

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I apologize this is a pretty basic question, although it seems like most people using grade are using it for android which doesn’t help me. I’d like to import a few libraries (OpenCSV and CLI parser) from maven and have apache spark as a provided compile library. Currently my build.gradle script is

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'idea'
group 'com.test'
version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

configurations {
    providedCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.8'

    providedCompile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.1'

    compile 'com.github.spullara.cli-parser:cli-parser:1.1'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.providedCompile
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.providedCompile

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    zip64 true
    from {
        (configurations.compile).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/license"
        exclude "META-INF/license/*"
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE*"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew clean --debug` build I get

```
    21:11:27.805 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to repo1.maven.org/151.101.24.209:443
    21:11:27.805 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to repo1.maven.org/151.101.24.209:443 with timeout 0
    21:11:27.930 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/github/spullara/cli-parser/cli-parser/1.1/cli-parser-1.1.pom
    21:11:27.931 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/github/spullara/cli-parser/cli-parser/1.1/cli-parser-1.1.jar
    21:11:27.931 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'com.github.spullara.cli-parser:cli-parser:1.1' in repository 'MavenLocal'.
    21:11:27.943 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in /private/var/folders/tb/j1t6f2sd4yvf6tyhtj_81tkr0000gn/T/gradle3280928141968750531.bin. Wrote root com.test:project:1.0:compile.
    21:11:27.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    21:11:27.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    21:11:27.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    21:11:27.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
    21:11:27.974 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/Users/user/workspace/project/build.gradle' line: 38
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve com.opencsv:opencsv:3.8.
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Required by:
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       com.test:project:1.0
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.opencsv:opencsv:3.8.
    21:11:27.975 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve com.github.spullara.cli-parser:cli-parser:1.1.
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   Required by:
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       com.test:project:1.0
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.github.spullara.cli-parser:cli-parser:1.1.
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager
    21:11:27.976 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
    21:11:27.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
    21:11:27.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
    21:11:27.978 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    21:11:27.978 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
    21:11:27.978 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
    21:11:27.978 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 7.244 secs
    21:11:27.980 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 2, cache instances: 2, modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
```

I’ve tried connecting to this url on my machine and have no problem doing so.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the MavenLocal? That's what the error is on

Comment: I have tried just having mavenCentral() and the same exception is thrown